# Right justify number with filler periods

Tags: formatting

How do I duplicate this in LaTex?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the question, but assuming what you don't know is how to put the dots, here's a way

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

what you come out with:
\begin{center}
  Average wage of employees \makebox[3cm]{\dotfill} $\$\,2.200$
\end{center}

Or did you just mean something like

Average wage of employees \dotfill\ $\$\,2.200$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so I don't have to specify the width of the ... box to flush right the number?

Comment: Ah, you mean just `Average wage of employees \dotfill\ $\$\,2.200$`?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. This works:
\indent\indent{Average wage or salary} \dotfill\ $\$\,2,806.45$\\

Comment: You should clarify the question, using `\indent` and ``\\`` is usually a bad sign. What do you want? Give us some context in the question, and we will came with better solutions.

Comment: Which '\' are you referring to? 

I am using the \indent\indent to indent the line twice so it stands out from a standard paragraph indent. I can get a similar result using \begin{quote} but the number won't flush as far right. 

\begin{quote} 
Average profit of owners \dotfill\ $\$\,5,000.00$\\
\end{quote}

Comment: I don't know why would you want it to start indented and end at the end of the line, in any case, if you use `addmargin` environment (available from `scrartcl` or other KOMA-Script classes or packages) you can adjust what you want. In any case, you are probably looking more for a list with items with that *style*. I would write a complete question asking with much more detail, you will probably have much better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tabular` solution, if you like an over kill:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}

what you come out with:

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{0.15\textwidth}p{\dimexpr0.85\textwidth-3\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
  & Average wage of employees \dotfill $\$\,2.200$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But then you can just put `\hspace*{1in}` in Manuel's solution before `Average` like

```
\hspace*{1in} Average.......
```

hence making this `tabular` solution over-kill.